# Install custom .apk without adb/Eclipse

Tags: android

Is it possible to install an .apk on a phone without using developer tools? Can it simply be dragged to a mounted SD card? My beta testers are not very tech-savvy or comfortable with the command line.

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install it from an SD card if you have a file browser on the phone, or you can download it via a webserver using the browser.

Comment: As long as the phone does not have protections against non-market applications.  My stock AT&T Samsung Galaxy S does not allow this to occur while many phones like the Verizon Incredible 2 allow you to change an Application Setting to allow non-market apps to be installed.  There are websites which allow you to do this as well, but you should really avoid sending APKs to untrusted third parties.

Comment: Thanks Chris but how do they install it from the SD card? Does it have to be copied to a specific location or will it appear in the launcher automatically?

Comment: @Barry Fruitman, once the user clicks on it in the file manager, it'll display the the option to install the package

Answer (score 4):

1. Copy the .apk file to DropBox (or any other cloud storage program. Box is another popular one).
2. Load DropBox on your Android device, navigate to the location of the .apk file and click Export.
3. Choose a location on the SD card to copy the .apk file to (eg /downloads).
4. Use a file explorer program (I use [ES File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)) and navigate to the location on the SD card where you exported the .apk file to in step 3.
5. Click the .apk file, which will install the application to your device (Note that you will have to turn on 'Unknown Sources' so that non-Android Market apps can be installed on your device if this setting is off).

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a web server that hosts your APKs. N.B. it would need to send `.apk` files with the right MIME type: `application/vnd.android.package-archive`.